# Display ALL cross-sell items in WooCommerce cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, cart

I'm trying to always display all cross-sell items in my cart.

The function `get_cross_sells()` located in the file [class-wc-cart.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/3611d4643791bad87a0d3e6e73e031bb80447417/plugins/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-cart.php) looks like this:

```php
/**
 * Gets cross sells based on the items in the cart.
 *
 * @return array cross_sells (item ids)
 */
public function get_cross_sells() {
    $cross_sells = array();
    $in_cart     = array();
    if ( ! $this->is_empty() ) {
        foreach ( $this->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
            if ( $values['quantity'] > 0 ) {
                $cross_sells = array_merge( $values['data']->get_cross_sell_ids(), $cross_sells );
                $in_cart[]   = $values['product_id'];
            }
        }
    }
    $cross_sells = array_diff( $cross_sells, $in_cart );
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids', wp_parse_id_list( $cross_sells ), $this );
}
```

The line `$cross_sells = array_diff( $cross_sells, $in_cart );` is what removes all cross-sell items that are already in the cart.

---

This "kinda" does it, but this way I'll have to make changes to the theme whenever I add or remove cross-sell items.

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids', 'my_custom_cross_sells' );
function my_custom_cross_sells( $cross_sell_ids ){ 
    $cross_sell_ids = [4782, 4777, 4776, 4783]; 
    return $cross_sell_ids;
}
```

How would I go about to override this function from my child-theme to always display all items?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids` filter hook will allow you to completely rewrite the `get_cross_sells()` function.

So to display ALL cross-sell items in WooCommerce cart, you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids( $cross_sells, $cart ) {
    // Initialize
    $cross_sells_ids_in_cart = array();
    
    // Loop through cart items
    foreach ( $cart->get_cart() as $cart_item_key => $values ) {
        if ( $values['quantity'] > 0 ) {
            // Merge one or more arrays
            $cross_sells_ids_in_cart = array_merge( $values['data']->get_cross_sell_ids(), $cross_sells_ids_in_cart );
        }
    }
    
    // Cleans up an array, comma- or space-separated list of IDs
    $cross_sells = wp_parse_id_list( $cross_sells_ids_in_cart );

    return $cross_sells;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids', 'filter_woocommerce_cart_crosssell_ids', 10, 2 );
```